# Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10 unexpected behavior with open()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and am seeing something unexpected based on other languages
I've worked with.

This code writes to a log file.

```
import datetime
import time

date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
mtime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
myfile = "log_file." + date + ".txt"

# fh = open(myfile, "a")   # Read program won't read new records if the open
                           # is done outside the loop                     
for x in range(100):
  fh = open(myfile, "a")   # Read program works as expected if this open 
  mtime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")  
  msg = str (mtime + " This is entry number " + str(x+1) + "\n")
  fh.write(msg)
  time.sleep( 2 )

fh.close
```

This code prints out new records written to the log file

```
import datetime
import time

date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
myfile = "log_file." + date + ".txt"

# This reads through all the records currently in the file.

lastLine = None
with open(myfile,'r') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            # print(line)        
            lastLine = line

# This prints out all of the new lines that are added to the file.

while True:
    with open(myfile,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    if lines[-1] != lastLine:
        lastLine = lines[-1]
        print(lines[-1])        
    time.sleep(1)
```

If I place the open() in the write code before the for loop the read code never
sees the new records.

If I place the open() in the write code inside the loop the read code prints out
the new lines added to the file as expected. Is this correct behavior? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

The file is running in buffered mode.  The reason that it works inside of the loop is that they file is being opened repeatedly and the buffer is likely flushed.  If you need writes to the file to be visible quickly in the reader, then you can disable buffering when you open the file with the `buffering=0` keyword argument.  This *should* make the new lines visible quickly in the reader.  You can also explicitly call `f.flush()` in the writer.  See the [docs on open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more details.

Comment: I changed the open outside to loop to be fh = open(myfile, "a", 1). It works as expected now, thanks!

Comment: I have been doing some more reading and it appears that turning buffering off with 0 only applies to binary files. I am looking at [link] https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open which states "buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy. Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1 to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. "  I just wanted to clarify in case someone else runs into this issue. Using 1 did the trick for me since my file is text.